# javascript array length not accessible in web page

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array in an external file:

```
<script src="assets/players.js"></script>

contents of above array:

window.players = [
"Addison, Jackson",
"Agron, Dmitry",
"Zuccarino, John"
]
```

I have tried to return the number of records to no avail:

```
<h3>Sample data file with <script>window.players.length;</script> names:</h3>
```

What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: Javascript won't just print the result be placing something like that into a location. You need to target something and then give that element the value you wish to display. **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/yokx4c27/

Comment: what about jquery? Would that work?

Comment: `jQuery` is a javascript plugin which is just pre-coded javascript so this is easy to do without having to use the `jQuery` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write out the length, than you would need to use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

```
<h3>Sample data file with <script>document.write(window.players.length)</script> names:</h3>
```

Or you could use DOM methods.

```
<h3>Sample data file with <span id="count"></span> names:</h3>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#count").innerHTML = window.players.length;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not a "pre-processed" language, like PHP. Change your code to:

```
<h3>Sample data file with <span id="output"></span> names:</h3>
<script>document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = window.players.length;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use template-style coding on the client side. Instead, you need to create any element that you can reference from the script and then manipulate its contents, e.g.

```
<h3 id="num"></h3>

 <script>
   document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = "Sample data file with " + window.players.length +" names"
 </script>
```